# linear combinatior of vector

Tags: linear-algebra

I have these three vector

$$
s_{1}= \begin{pmatrix} 
-2 \\
1 \\
-1 
\end{pmatrix}
\;\;\;\;\;
s_{2}= \begin{pmatrix}
1 \\
-1 \\
-3
\end{pmatrix}
\;\;\;\;\;
s_{3}= \begin{pmatrix}
4 \\
7 \\
-1
\end{pmatrix}
$$

and the following vector is formed as a linear combination of the three vectors above
$$
s=\begin{pmatrix}
3 \\
-1 \\
5
\end{pmatrix}
$$

How is the vector $s$ formed from $s_{1}, s_{2}, s_{3}$? This seems simple but I can't determine how the vector $s$ is formed. Please help

Answer (score 1):

you must solve the system
$$-2\alpha+\beta+4\gamma=3$$
$$\alpha-\beta+7\gamma=-1$$
$$-\alpha-3\beta-\gamma=5$$
we obtain $$\alpha=-2$$ and $$\beta=-1$$ and $$\gamma=0$$

Comment: You misread the question. I need to determine the vector $s$ from $s_{1}, s_{2}, s_{3}$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: suppose $a_1,$ $a_2,$ and $a_3$ are real numbers such that:

$a_1s_1+a_2s_2+a_3s_3=s$

And solve 3 equations with 3 unknowns.